# Mysql query resultset in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

I am using the bash script to connect to the mysql database and execute a query.

I use the below script to connect to the database and execute the query.

```
#!/bin/bash
Total_Results=$(mysql -h server-name -P 3306 -u username-ppassword -D dbname<<<"select URL  from Experiment where URL_Exists = 1");
for URL in "$Total_Results";
do
echo $URL
var=$(curl -s --head $URL | head -n 1 | grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23]..")
echo "$var"
if [ -z "$var" ]
then
echo "Ok we do not have a valid link and the value needs to be updated as -1 here"
else
echo "we will update the value as 1 from here"
fi
done
```

The problem is the result set is considered as a one whole result and I am getting inside the else loop only once (we will update the value as 1 from here is printed only once). I have 2500 valid URLs and I expect 2500 echoes of `we will update the value as 1 from here`.

How can I process each and every row as a single result from mySQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql` seems to output the results to a shell variable in a single line. One way round this is to write the contents to a temporary file, then process in a while loop.

**EDIT**
On my system IFS="\n" before the mysql command (when the results are assigned to a shell variable) gives the correct multi-line output.
e.g.

```
 IFS="\n"
 Total_results=$(mysql.....)
```

=============== End of Edit ==========================

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --silent -h server-name -P 3306 -u username-ppassword -D dbname<<<"select URL  from Experiment where URL_Exists = 1" > tmp_results

while read URL
do 
   echo $URL
   var=$(curl -s --head $URL | head -n 1 | grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23]..")
   echo "$var"
   if [ -z "$var" ]
   then
     echo "Ok we do not have a valid link and the value needs to be updated as -1 here"
   else
     echo "we will update the value as 1 from here"
   fi
done < tmp_results
```

Comment: Can't you just parse it directly? Like `mysqlcommand | while read URL; do ... ; done` ? Why use a temp file?

Comment: Yes I'm sure there is an easier way - but when assigning to a shell variable the output is a single line.

Comment: I get an error as /tmp_results no such file or directory. However, the file is getting generated as expected.

Comment: sorry typo - have removed the /.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a variable or a temp file for this, just parse the `mysql` command directly by piping to the `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql <<<"select URL from Experiment where URL_Exists = 1" |

while IFS='\n' read URL
do
  echo $URL
  var=$(curl -s --head $URL | head -n 1 | grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23]..")
  echo "$var"
  if [ -z "$var" ]
  then
    echo "Ok we do not have a valid link and the value needs to be updated as -1 here"
  else
    echo "we will update the value as 1 from here"
  fi
done
```

Comment: @suspectus facepalm! Of course, there will be spaces in the output. Thanks.

Comment: @terdon - nice solution.